# If $\sum_{n=1}^{N}f(n)=b$ for all $N$ as natural so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)=b$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This seems clean it looks enough just take a very large natural number to this holds but I'm not sure if it really does since I was told so many times that we can't further a afirmation from $N$ to $N \rightarrow \infty$ so I'm doubting if I'm able to on this case.

Comment: Show $f(n)=0$ for all $n>1.$

Comment: $f(1)+f(2)+...+f(n)=b$ and $f(1)+f(2)+...+f(n+1)=b$. Subtract and you get $f(n)=0$ and $f(1)=b$

Comment: @Wolfuryo you get $f(n+1)=0,$ not $f(n)=0.$

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)$ needs a definition and the usual one is $\lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}f(n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)$ needs a definition to handle $\infty$.

The usual one is $\lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}f(n)$, though possibly with a caveat about absolute convergence.

So here $\lim\limits_{N \to \infty} b$, which is $b$.

Comment: sorry, will the $lim$, $d(.)/dx$, $\int$ operators always keep equality to hold?

Comment: @DaviAmérico you would have to give an example to show what you mean.  A lot of things do not pass through limits

Comment: I will put it out on another question